# Is there a way to get values form a swiffy animation

Tags: javascript, html, actionscript-3, google-swiffy

let's assume that i'm detecting the number of mouse clicks in flash

for that ive used the code

```
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
plus.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,aaa)
var i:int=0;
function aaa(e:MouseEvent)
{    
    i++;
    var a:Number= Number(input1.text)+Number(input2.text);
    answer.text=String(i);  
}
```

and i'm displaying it in `answer` text box, i converted this to HTML5 using `swiffy` and i want to get the value of the `answer` text box in a javascript popop right after i click the plus button ? i tried converting it into  swiffy and inspecting the textbox with chrome and it doesn't detect the text box it detects the whole canvas as an `SVG`.

feel free to correct me if i'm wrong in AS3 (just a beginner).

Comment: why using two technologies at once, when using one will suffice?

Comment: this is just a concept @Vesper i want to pass values to the aspx from the swf file (which isnt supported in mobile devices)

Comment: @MAD4RA So you should consider Haxe.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to spit your value out to a javascript function as follows.

```
function aaa(e:MouseEvent)
{    
    i++;
    var a:Number= Number(5)+Number(4);
    answer.text=String(i);
    //getURL("javascript:swiffyClicked(" + answer.text + ")"); /* AS2 way */
    navigateToURL(new URLRequest("javascript:swiffyClicked(" + answer.text + ");"), "_self"); /* AS3 way */
}
```

Then create the JS function at the top of your converted html file.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
      function swiffyClicked(answer){
        alert(answer);
      }
</script>
```

Comment: are you .. there .. need your help