# Swiffy - set up a clicktag - syntax issue

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, google-swiffy

I am working with Flash CS6 / AS3 exported with Swiffy for HTML 5.
I would like to include a clickTag on a simple button but cannot find the proper syntax.

The basic code below, generated by Flash works fine:

```
this.myButton.addEventListener("click", fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2);
function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2() {
window.open("http://www.mysite.com", "_blank");
}
```

Then I added the javascript code given by Google Swiffy to set the variable in the webpage (no bug so far):

```
stage.setFlashVars("clickTAG=http://www.mysite.com");
stage.start();
```

In Flash (AS3), I tried the usual code:

```
var paramList:Object = loaderInfo.parameters;
var urlRequest:URLRequest = new URLRequest(paramList["clickTAG"]);

function fl_ClickToGoToWebPage_2() {
window.open(clickTAG, "_blank");
}
```

But that does not work :( and the variable does not come through. This even bugs the animation.

Question is, how should I write the Flash code lines to get the variable passed to my window.open function? What I am missing?

Thanks a lot for you help

Answer (score 0):

If you are sure that clickTAG is correctly set, try the method at this link using navigateToURL:

[Is there a way to get values form a swiffy animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20649625/is-there-a-way-to-get-values-form-a-swiffy-animation)

Send your link string from the swiffy to a javascript function & do your window.open stuff there.